# What does the NPC in Deus Ex: HR say about Lower and Upper Hengsha?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

This might be a utterly simple question, but do you remember a Hengsha citizen saying something like:

> Upper Hengsha is for boring big braaaaaaains! Come to Lower Hengsha, more fun here!

I can’t remember exactly what he says. Do you?

I don’t know how else to look for it. Google nor DuckDuckGo offer any results.

If you happen to get a YouTube video with it, the better.

Thanks and apologies if you don’t consider this a really important question!

PS: I couldn’t find the game script, so that’s why I’m asking.